# Looking to make this menu responsive for smaller screens and devices

Tags: html, css

[This image is what the page looks like full screen.][1]

[This is what I would like the menu to look like on a smaller screen.][2]

I would like the menu to look like this to be a vertical menu. When you click on one of the headings, the sub menu appears. My goal is to have this more for the mobile devices. Any thoughts? I have read so many articles on how to do this, but cannot make it work with my menu below: Any thoughts will help. I am having a lot of trouble getting this to work and be responsive.

Comment: Are you using a particular framework?  Do you have access to jquery or bootstrap?

Comment: What problems are you specifically running into when you try to make this mobile responsive?

Comment: Do you have mockups of what you are supposed to turn the menu into on a mobile device?  Would you mind attaching a screenshot of what the menu currently looks like?

Comment: I have added a screen shot of what the code currently looks like. I am looking to disable the background video, hide the container on the left.

Comment: On the flip side, I attached what I would like this menu to change into.

Comment: I have tried your basic menu designs, but cannot figure out how to adjust them with the tags I am using in the code above. All examples I find us <ul> classes and such. Mine just looks a little different. Sorry if I am sounding confusing, this part of CSS/HTML is a little out of my world.

Comment: I do know that I am going to need to use a media query, but I am not sure what the css would look like to design that type of menu.

Comment: So, is your question "how do I responsively style a menu?" or is it "how do I build the mobile menu in the attached screenshot?" ?

Comment: Great question:

I guess both, but I more importantly would need to responsively style a menu with the code of the menu provided above.

Comment: kk.  Do you have access to jQuery or Bootstrap?

Comment: I do not, but I can download an application if need be!

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using Bootstrap. It's really simple to bring into your project and you can find their code for a responsive navbar [here](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/#responsive-behaviors).

Comment: I'm not saying this is a bad advice, but this is not an answer to the question. This is better off as a comment, rather than an answer.